# Newbie Javascript: Remaining calories

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I am very new and practicing functions right now

I made this to create a simple remaining calories calculator, but I wanted to ask:

When I have originally created a value that already calculates **the difference** between, lets say, **caloriesMen** and **caloriesToday** and named it **caloriesLeft** (so I literally wrote ' **let caloriesLeft = caloriesMen - caloriesToday** ') but it came up with **NaN** which is somewhat understandable.

But when I did that in the alert() it understood what I wanted
(e.g. 'You have ' + **(caloriesMen - caloriesToday)** + ' calories left to consume today!')

1. Could you tell me why is that?
2. How would you made this code (better/cleaner)?

My code and vars:

```
let gender;
let caloriesMen = 2500;
let caloriesWomen = 2000;
let caloriesToday;

function calCalc() {

gender = prompt('Are you man or woman?') 
    if (gender == 'man') {
        caloriesToday = prompt('How many calories have you already consumed today?');
        alert('You have ' + (caloriesMen - caloriesToday) + ' calories left to consume today!');
    } else if (gender == 'woman') {
        caloriesToday = prompt('How many calories have you already consumed today?');
        alert('You have ' + (caloriesWomen - caloriesToday) + ' calories left to consume today!');
    }
    
}

calCalc();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining `caloriesToday` as a integer, so `let caloriesToday = 0;` otherwise its value will be `undefined` so you cant subract that from another number

Answer (score 1):

```
let gender;
let caloriesMen = 2500;
let caloriesWomen = 2000;
let caloriesToday;
let caloriesLeft;
function calCalc() {

gender = prompt('Are you man or woman?') 
    if (gender == 'man') {
        caloriesToday = prompt('How many calories have you already consumed today?');
        caloriesLeft = caloriesMen - caloriesToday;
        alert('You have ' + caloriesLeft + ' calories left to consume today!');
    } else if (gender == 'woman') {
        caloriesToday = prompt('How many calories have you already consumed today?');
        caloriesLeft = caloriesWomen - caloriesToday;
        alert('You have ' + caloriesLeft + ' calories left to consume today!');
    }
    
}

calCalc();
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ben Coupe stated, you need to initialize your variables to avoid `undefined` values contaminating everything it touches.

"Cleaner code" is a matter of taste. I'd personally avoid the if/else with an object with keys for the different genders. Don't use global variables if you don't have to. It works fine to define your variables inside the function.

```
function calCalc() {
    let gender = prompt('Are you man or woman?');
    let caloriesPerGender = {'man': 2500, 'woman': 2000};
    let caloriesToday = prompt('How many calories have you already consumed today?');
    alert('You have ' + (caloriesPerGender[gender] - caloriesToday) + ' calories left to consume today!');
}

calCalc();
```

You'll probably want to check your inputs too, if someone enters "monkey" on gender or "abc" in the calories input, your function will crash.